# Codeigniter Rest And Ajax not getting desired results

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, rest

My codeigniter controller is set up as follows:

```
<?php

include('./application/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Restful extends REST_Controller{

public function user_get()
{
    //URL as such:
    //  http://localhost/rest/restful/user/id/1
    //notice array('returned'$this->get(id)) ->>>> get the id thats being sent 
    $data = array('returned: '.$this->get('id'));
    $this->response($data);
    //returns :
    //  xml <item> returned: 1</item> /xml
    }
}
```

trying to access it from a view that is set up as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<title style="font-family:Logo">Ajax</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--this is jQuery with only the ajax part-->
<script src="../ajax.js"></script>
</header>
<body>

<div id="e">

</div>


<script>
function getrest(){
    var output;
    res=$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/rest/restful/user?id=1',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(output){
            document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = output;
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    getrest();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Problem is that the result i keep getting from the view is:
[object Document]

What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT:
If i type this into the URL
rest/restful/user?id=1

i get this result from the rest controller:
    
    returned: 1

Thanks
Jason

Comment: What does your `routes.php` look like?

Comment: Have you tried `url: 'http://localhost/restful/user_get/?id=1',`?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to define function name as "user", not "user_get". So controller code will be

```
public function user()
{

$data = array('returned: '.$this->get('id'));
$this->response($data);

}
}
```

Comment: it has to be user_get -> and if i straight up run the controller and pass it the values it works. but when i call it from ajax it just gives me [Object Document] :/

Comment: there is a whole tutorial on codeigniter rest @ nettuts and i followed it here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/